# In CyberSource test account, where is 'Transaction Security Keys' setting?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

In Payment Gateway of Cyber Source

Test Acoount Click [here](https://ebctest.cybersource.com/ebctest/)

There is not **Marchant Information -> Transaction Security Keys**

we refere Click [here](http://www.cybersource.com/support_center/implementation/downloads/soap_api/SOAP_toolkits.pdf)

but not solved it.

Answer (score 5):

When you created the test account, you received an email with activation links for two accounts:
- Account Admin account
- Merchant Admin account

You need to activate the second one, log in with that and you will find it in the 'Account Management' menu.

Comment: created new account then your solution worked for me thanks @atika

Answer (score 3):

The activation email you received is probably for the account admin. After you activate this, you go to Account Management > User Administration. From there, click on the "Users for merchant" radio button and select the merchant from the drop down(probably the only item). Create a new user. Login as that user and the option should now be there.

Answer (score 1):

While logging in with the Merchant Admin, make sure the merchant ID is correct. You just need to put the merchant id instead of merchantid_acct, change it to merchantid.

Comment: this comment should be merged with the comment above as both are needed and useful

Answer (score 0):

It is late but I have found out resolution. I faced same issue.

Login via merchant account ( without _acc) you will see the  Account Management tab, click on Transaction Security Keys and do whatever you want.